# For a bounded linear operator $\phi$, show that $||\phi(x)|| \leq ||\phi|| \cdot ||x||$, where $||\phi|| = sup_{||x|| = 1} ||\phi(x)||$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Wernet Greub, at page 206, it is given that

> $\phi$ is bounded iff for any $x\in E$, $\exists M$ s.t $$||\phi(x)||
>  \leq M \cdot ||x||$$
>   Now let  $\phi : E \to E$ is a bounded linear transformation.Then we denote
>   $$||\phi|| = sup_{||x|| = 1} ||\phi(x)||,$$ and it follows that 
>   $$||\phi(x)|| \leq ||\phi|| \cdot ||x||, \quad x\in E.$$

However, I couldn't figure out how did he arrived to that conclusion. I mean for $||x|| = 1$, we have $||\phi(x)|| \leq M \cdot ||x|| = M$, hence by defition of supremum, we should have 
$$sup_{||x|| = 1} ||\phi(x)|| = ||\phi|| \leq M,$$
hence for an arbitrary $y \in E$
$$||\phi|| \cdot ||y|| \leq M \cdot ||y||,$$
so I couldn't derive the same conclusion.

Comment: @GuyFsone I didn't see that question, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x=0$ and for $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$ you agree with the conclusion. So fix an arbitrary $y\neq 0$ and note that
$$
\left\|\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|=1.
$$
It follows by the linearity of $\phi$ that
$$
\phi(y)=\|y\|\phi\left(\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right) \le \|y\|\,\|\phi\|.
$$

Comment: I guess you are still editing the answer ?

Comment: No, should I? $\text{ }$

Comment: That fact is already given by our assumption that $\phi$ is bounded.

Comment: See my last edit.

Comment: It seems to me that you assume that the definition that $\phi$ is "bounded" if $M:=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|\phi(x)\|<\infty$ and you want to prove that $M<\infty$ if and only if $\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|\phi(x)\|}{\|x\|}<\infty$. Now, one direction is obvious. The other one is shown in my answer. Anyway, you can find it in every basic book of functional analysis.

Comment: In the question, supremum of image of unit vectors are denoted as $||\phi||$, that was the problematic part, but I have undertood the logic, thank. If you correct the that notation, I will accept the answer. Otherwise, it will be a wrong answer to another person who will be looking to this question.